# Transfer Data from Android Mobile to Android Tablet

Tags: file-transfer, file-management

I want to synchronize my Android Phone and Tablet.

How can I copy my pictures and music to my Tablet?

I don't want to upload all my data to a Cloud service (my Internet connection is slow and expensive).

It would be great if there would exist an automated process where I don't need to select all files by hand.

Comment: Does it have to be USB – or would a WiFi solution be acceptable as well? Not involving the cloud, of course, just your Android devices and your PC.

Comment: That would be fine too. I thought USB would be the easiest solution, but I can use Wifi.

Comment: In that case: Take a look at my answer. Works great for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If WiFi is acceptable, you might wish to take a look at [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync-lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). Aside from cloud services (Dropbox & Co), it can also deal with Samba (Windows shares), FTP, SFTP (ssh with Unix/Linux), and more. You can define "Folder Pairs", i.e. which folder on your Android device should be synchronized with what folder on the remote machine. Sync can be done uni- and bi-directional.

I'm using that with all my Android devices and my PC, to keep different stuff in sync. Easy to do with e.g. photos or the music collection: Add a file on one device, and it gets synced across. *FolderSync* even supports [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), which gives you plenty of possibilities to deal with: Having the device synced as soon as you're at home, or only when connected to a power source, at specific times, whatever.